# Is my camera infected with fungus?

Tags: lens, old-lenses, fungus

I am new to this forum. I just wanted to ask if this is fungus in my lens and how worried should I be?
I am just using this lens with my Nikon F3. Is it possible that my camera got infected? I don´t mind throwing away the lens but I am worried that my new one will get infected too. What should I do?

Thank you,
Jakob

[image: lens fungus]

[image: lens fungus 2]

Comment: Was your camera stored with the affected lens attached to it? The 2nd photo is not sharp at all; can you upload a new version of it, which is sharp and focused on the rear element of the lens?

Comment: It's extremely difficult to tell much of anything from the low resolution images provided. The first image could be anything from surface scratches to hazing to, yes, fungus (or various combinations of all of the above). There's no way to tell from the very limited information you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

First, fungus that grows on glass grows *very* slowly, and likely will not bother you or other lenses, directly. However,the smear might also be condensation from plastic [outgassing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outgassing) plasticizer. Evaporating plasticizer from car parts can leave a similar smear on the windows.

In any event, you can [try to clean](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/how-to-clean-camera-lens/) the outer surfaces of the lens... but if the mess is on the inside, professional cleaning may cost more than a replacement lens.